# How do delete options properly for WordPress multi-sites?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on uninstall.php script and want to know how to properly delete option in multi-sites environment. So far I have the following:

```
if ( ! is_multisite() ) {
    delete_option('my-option-name');
} else {
    # Get all sites 
    $sites = # Not sure how to get this

    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        switch_to_blog( $site);
        delete_option('my-options-name')
    }

    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Or does the following code achieve the same thing?

```
if ( ! is_multisite() ) {
    delete_option('my-option-name');
} else {
    delete_site_option('my-option-name');
}
```